# API-first rest endpoint not listed in jhipster-gateway API section (swagger-ui)

Tags: microservices, jhipster, swagger-ui, api-gateway, openapi-generator

Using jhipster 5.7.2

I created an api-gateway, and two micro-services.
In the first one, I created an entity and it works perfectly behind the gateway.  The gateway displays the api endpoints for the generated entity.

I generated the second micro-service but this time I had already an api defined in a yml file so I chose 'API-first'.
My api was defined using open-api 3.
I successfully generated the code for my api, using the [instructions there](https://www.jhipster.tech/doing-api-first-development/), and tested calling direcly my micro-service endpoint using curl : it worked as expected at this point.

The problem : when I put that micro-service behind the gateway, the gateway does not see the api.  When I go to the api menu, my micro-service shows in the dropdown but when I select it, it shows no endpoints.

One weird thing I found while searching is that when I call the following url on my micro-service directly : http://localhost:8082/v2/api-docs (as pointed in the 'welcome page' of the micro-service), I get :

```
{"swagger":"2.0","info":{"description":"my micro-service API documentation","version":"0.0.1","title":"api-first micro-service API","contact":{},"license":{}},"host":"localhost:8082","basePath":"/"}
```

It says 'swagger 2.0' when my yml file declared openapi 3.0.1.
I searched and found [this issue](https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/7966), which says :

> Swagger UI very old version (2.2.10) is used which does not provide
>   the support for Open API

I though openapi was the problem, so I rewrote the yml file to swagger 2.0 and finally I have the same exact problem : micro-service API works but seems not visible to the gateway.

I'm starting to wonder if it's a problem on my side only.

Comment: Does your API endpoint begin with `api`?  Swagger is configured to look only for those endpoints by default https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app-microservice/blob/ac09370c3fcd178339a2fdcca0ca626c366daf1c/src/main/resources/config/application.yml#L135

Comment: Thank you buddy, that did it :)  I have to mention that after fixing the problem, openapi3 was working fine.  endpoint url are a bit weird tough : http://localhost:8080/expires/api/expires.  I will probably just change the configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, JHipster configures Swagger to only list API endpoints beginning with `api`.  This is configured in `application.yml`, change `default-include-pattern` to include other paths.  For example, to include endpoints beginning with either `/api/` or `/expires/`, you can use the following:

```
swagger:
    default-include-pattern: /(api|expires)/.*
```