# jhipster, api-first approach, the generated api now shown in swagger-ui

Tags: jhipster, openapi

I am following the guideline https://www.jhipster.tech/doing-api-first-development/ generated endpoint interfaces and implmented PetApiDelegateImpl.

The “pet/findByStatus" is accessiable:

```
 curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' 'http://localhost:8080/v2/pet/findByStatus?status=pending'
[ {
  "id" : 7918631312207652864,
  "category" : null,
  "name" : null,
  "photoUrls" : [ ],
  "tags" : null,
  "status" : "pending"
}]
```

However, in swagger, no any petstore api showed:
[image]

Is anything i am missing?

Comment: found the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54171883/api-first-rest-endpoint-not-listed-in-jhipster-gateway-api-section-swagger-ui

Comment: Maybe you could contribute by improving the doc https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster.github.io/blob/master/pages/doing_api_first_development.md